# wkhtmltopdf - QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: linux, debian

How to run `wkhtmltopdf` headless?!

Installation on Debian Whezzy

```
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Command

```
wkhtmltopdf --title "$SUBJECT" -q $SOURCEFILE $OUTPUTFILE
```

Error

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Comment: Download relevant `.tar.xz` file from the [GitHub release page](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/tag/0.12.4) and copy the binary from `wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf` to `/usr/bin/`. [[from here](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/82)]

Comment: The upper comment is the 2018/19 answer (sorry can't post this as an answer). Here a small script to make it work smoothly: https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/blob/master/travis/before-script.sh

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 i was stuck for some time and google kept sending me to this SO...but this link: https://gist.github.com/srmds/2507aa3bcdb464085413c650fe42e31d#wkhtmltopdf-0125----ubuntu-1604-x64 finally did the trick.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2037), and the fix hasn't been brought to the Debian repositories. Quoting *ashkulz* (who closed the bug report) :

> You're using the version of wkhtmltopdf in the debian repositories, which does not support running headless.

So you can either...

- [Download `wkhtmltopdf` from source](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) and compile it (see the instructions in [the INSTALL.md file](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/INSTALL.md) ; you may remove the `--recursive` option from their `git clone` line, if you already have Qt 4.8 installed).
- Run it inside `xvfb`, [as suggested by *masterkorp* in the bug report](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2037#issuecomment-62019521).

Comment: If you do not want to build wkhtmltopdf from source, you might want to try phantomjs with: `phantomjs /usr/share/doc/phantomjs/examples/rasterize.js $url $pdf`.

Comment: Have now downloaded the source to `/var/bin/wkhtmltopdf`.. `cd /var/bin/wkhtmltopdf && scripts/build.py wheezy-amd64` => `-bash: scripts/build.py: Permission denied`

Comment: @clarkk You shouldn't download the source to `/var/bin`. Take it to your home directory and follow the instructions in the `INSTALL.md` file, for your distribution.

Comment: I still get the error

Comment: You still haven't read the installation instructions :) Delete the source and download them as they suggest it, through Git cloning. The rest requires `sudo`, so you shouldn't get any *permission denied* problem. Also make sure the Python scripts you're running are executable (which should be the case if you download the source properly).

Comment: Or just grab the latest linux generic binary from the website: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: I had similar problem. thanks for for well described answer

Comment: this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50153456/26130

Answer (score 61):

There is a more easy way to make John WH Smith solution.

Just install xvfb from apt and then, you can run:

```
xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf
```

(just put `xvfb-run` before any wkhtmltopdf command.)

Comment: For posterity, this works on a Raspberry Pi, Raspbian Jessie as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Also if you get **xvfb-run: error: xauth command not found** then just `sudo apt-get install xauth` and try again!

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: if you don't have the `xvfb-run` command in CentOS: `yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`

Comment: xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start

Comment: @tokam can you provide more information?

Comment: @tokam just add `-a` as argument. This error may occur if you call multiple xvfb without proper delay between them.

Answer (score 13):

on your command line type like this

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

then run your `qt` applications

Comment: this may not be the right answer for the question at large, but I came here from google for a different similar problem that this solved.

Comment: Solved my problem on raspberry pi3, qt5.7.0, gui error:    "**QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted**" .

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Raspberry Pi3 I get an error: "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted"

Comment: My raspberry Pi always boots in command line mode.

Comment: Solved my problem while trying to run OBS Studio from terminal. Thank you :-)

Comment: I have installed `xauth` then `export DISPLAY=:0 ` works fine to me. Thanks!